# Authentication in BIRT through Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, authentication, birt

I am using rails application which runs on Redis server. I also have BIRT(Business Intelligence and Reporting Tools) reports on Apache Tomcat server to generate reports which is hosted on Tomcat server. An authentication is done when the user logs in to the rails application through Redis server. However, there is no additional authentication for the Tomcat server to view the reports.

I do not want the user to see the URL of the reports. I am using iFrames to display the reports to the user as this will prevent the user from seeing the URL. But the user may use the Inspect Element / Firebug to get the URL of the report and access it individually without any authentication which defeats the purpose of using iFrames.

1. Is it possible to provide authentication when the user views the reports?
2. Is it possible to hide / mask the URL so that it is not accessible through the Inspect element / Firebug and hence the reports will not accessible individually also.

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

1. This question [Parameters with Connection Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484366/parameters-with-connection-profile) indicates how to use property binding get a User ID and Password from a parameter at report run time (it goes on to ask a harder question).  Tomcat would not "know" the values without this user input.
2. I am assuming you want to hide/mask the URL because in the default Tomcat set up server and port information are displayed. You can use DNS naming changes/directions to hide the URL.

The user uses a link like

```
http://reports.YOU.com/run?__report=T_im_ByID.rptdesign
```

And is returned the report from

```
http://server01:8080/Birt/run?__report=T_im_ByID.rptdesign
```

I am not positive that there is no way around the DNS change but when I run my BIRT reports through firebug I am only seeing the 'reports.YOU.com'