# Parameters with Connection Profile

Tags: birt

In BIRT, is it possible to setup a connection profile which accepts the username/password as a parameter?

With a standard data source, I can use the "Property Binding" tab to set a report parameter to be used as the username an password. However, when I create a data source for a connection profile, I do not see a "Property Binding" tab. I also do not see any way to edit an existing data source in a connection profile or how to get to more options for the data source (when it is part of a connection profile).

Screenshot of the Property Binding tab which is available for non-Connection Profile Data Sources:
[image: Edit Property Bindings]

Screenshot of the Create Data Source for Connection Profile - no property binding tab :(
[image: Create Data Source for Connection Profile]

Answer (score 1):

U can edit exsisting connection profile.

Select Menu    Window-Show View->Others->Data source explorer...Now u can view existing profiles.right click and take properties of corresponding profile,here u can edit username and password